# Responsively Scaled Image in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, image, resize, responsive-design

I'm creating a slideshow with jQuery Cycle, and I need to be able to resize the images in the slideshow responsively with css.  So far, cycle has been so controlling of the width and height of the images that I haven't been able to do it.  I have been able to achieve the images resizing according to window width when I refresh the page, but the images won't dynamically resize when resizing the window. I'm trying to work out a solution in Javascript, but I'd really like to be able to get away with pure css.

Comment: Can you prepare a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), please?!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rEjXX/

There's no attempt in the fiddle at the responsive resizing, this is just an example so you guys know where I'm coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery Cycle is setting widths inline on the `<img>` tags. That's the first problem. I would try removing that, it looks like [the options](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/options.html) for Cycle has this value `slideResize`, try setting that to `false` or `0`.

The next step would be setting a max-width on the container, and `width: 100%` on the imgs.

Comment: This is actually it, I'm pretty sure.  The thing is I'm still finding that I have to manually go in with Javascript and set the height of the container in pixels, since setting it to height:auto just lets the images overflow from the container.

Comment: Try adding `overflow:hidden;` to the container.

Comment: That causes the image, still of larger size than the container, to be cut off and the part that would overflow is just not rendered.  I'm basically asking it to be magic by setting the image to 100% of the width of the container (which is set to 100% of its container), while maintaining aspect ratio.  The image can shrink to the correct width, but either it doesn't maintain aspect ratio, or the container shrinks to a much smaller size than the image, causing the image to overflow.

Comment: Ah, I think `max-width:100%;` on the `img` along with `width:100%;` should pull it in then if I'm picturing what your saying correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion - but you'll probably want to use something like JavaScript (or an AJAX service or something) to handle this because if you were to handle resizing the images within the browser that is going to put an incredible amount of strain on the browser to handle all of the resizing and scaling.

You may want to target specific resolutions and serve the images based on the "closest" viewport size accordingly.

Comment: Javascript is client-side so that wouldn't put any less strain on the browser... css puts a ton less strain on the browser than javascript and it's faster than using ajax to send a request all the way to the server just to resize an image.  I know it's possible to resize the image in javascript, but I'm mainly looking to see if it's possible in css, or if anyone has css-oriented suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the width or height of the image related to a container

```
.container{width:200px}.container img {width:100%}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think I'm gonna have to resign to working in javascript.  It seems that jQuery cycle forces so much css onto the images and container that I'll have too many things to deal with.  I think I was hoping to see if someone specifically had any experience with jQuery cycle.  Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Set the img elements width to 100% and height to auto to take aspect ratio into account. If you don't want the image to be 100% of the browser, add a container element.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems as though jQuery cycle does so much stuff with the elements that it mucks up the container and the images, and I can't really affect it the way I need to.  Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet to make a image responsive, this is without it being inside a container btw.

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Now, it will stretch to the width of the page, but if its contained it will stretch to the width of the container, the thing to try is, making the container grow and shrink as well.